# Get a date x days prior to an existing date with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have a date value that is in my Angular application and is stored in local storage.

If I execute the code

```
$scope.selectedDate = localStorage.getItem('selDate');
```

it will return (currently) '11-4-2015'

What I want is for it to return that date MINUS 85 days.

I have tried:

```
var hearingOffset = 85;
var selectedDate = new Date(localStorage.getItem('selDate').replace(/-/g, '/') - hearingOffset);
```

I get "Invalid Date"

What do I do to get a proper date here?

Comment: Is selectedDate a Date type or a String? You're not going to be able to subtract two strings to perform your date operation.

Comment: That's my question. How do I: (1) Get the value from local storage (2) Convert it to a date; and (3) subtract 85 days from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) could do this easily.

`moment(date).subtract(85, 'days').toDate()`

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will be helpful

```
var d = new Date(); // today!
var x = 85; // go back 85 days!
d.setDate(d.getDate() - x);
```

Once you get the date you can convert it to required format

**EDIT**

On subtraction we will get the result in millisecond, so have to convert to date.

```
var d = new Date('11-4-2015');
var x = 85; // go back 85 days!
var y=d.setDate(d.getDate() - x);
var date = new Date(y);
document.getElementById('dateHolder').innerHTML=date;
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hb3hm4sv/1/)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. In my question I already have a string that represents a date. I need to convert that string to a date and then subtract 85 days from it. How to do that?